# Best approach Iterate through the rows of a dataframe in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, performance, loops, pyspark, parallel-processing

i have a requirement where i need to sort my dataframe based on card-member(CM) number and then iterate through each rows and based on the values of couple of cols i need to do some operation. As such i am looking in the best possible ways to iterate/loop through the dataframe as well as do it in parallel for optimize performance.

Note i am using PySpark.

I have gone through similar posts and majority talk about doing the collect()/toLocalIterator() operation as straightaway solution but i don't want do that because that will load the entire data in driver node and my dataframe size can be actually quite huge (~50Gb) in each run. As such going through multiple posts i have came up with two approach. Can anybody please help me to validate which approach should be best

1-) Find the distinct CM number list from the df and then use Select to select specific rows for a particular CM value and then do a collect on that. This will still load data in driver node but the volume will still be less than the entire volume. Do the operation required and repeat the above steps until the distinct list of CM ends.

2-) use the rdd.map(custom_function) after the dataframe is sorted based on CM number. But not sure if i can achieve parallelism through this.

Appreciate any pointers regarding the approach

Comment: Can you please share what your input data is (schema, how large is it) and which actual calculations you want to do? The correct approach will depend on those parameters, so without that it is harder to give you a proper answer.